# .NET Core 3.1 GetService return null

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am new to .NET Core and I got stuck on this.

In my `startup.cs`, I have

```
services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
```

and I have created a `IHostedService`:

```
 services.AddHostedService<CooldownExpiredService>();
```

inside my `CooldownExpiredService`, I have the following code

```
using (var emailScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var _emailService = emailScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<EmailService>();
}
```

but the object I get is null. How can I get the `EmailService` inside from `HostedService`?

Answer (score 3):

i dont knwo why i should have use the interface.

```
emailScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IEmailService>()
```

Comment: Because you've **registered** the `IEmailService` interface to be resolved to an `EmailService` instance, if you ask for it - that's the **whole point** of dependency injection...... and it would be **even better** if you've defined `IEmailService` to be a dependency of your `CooldownExpiredService` and injected that dependency via constructor injection - instead of using an explicit call to `.GetService<>()` which is often considered to be an **anti-pattern** that should be avoided if ever possible

Answer (score 1):

You can add Extension Method for all Services
first : add class =>

```
public static class ServiceTool
    {
        private static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
        public static IServiceCollection Create(IServiceCollection servicesProvider)
        {
            ServiceProvider = servicesProvider.BuildServiceProvider();
            return servicesProvider;
        }

        public static T Resolve<T>()
        {
            return ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
        }
    }
```

And go to the Startup and add it

```
ServiceTool.Create(services);
```

For use in controller write on constructor controller
example:

```
_logRepository = ServiceTool.Resolve<ILogRepository>();
```